# How can I read the properties of a node group in a blend file?

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor

Is it possible with Python to detect if a nodegroup is embedded in a frame in another blend file without adding it first?

I have several blend files with the following structure:

[image]

The main group always contains a certain name (in this example "_TEST"), and in it are other nodegroups.
Some of them are embedded in frames, some are not.

And from another file, before I add/process a certain nodegroup from these files, I want to check if it is embedded in a frame or not.

Basically reading the file works fine, and I can add the nodes, but in this step I always get only the name of the group, but not its properties, like `parent`:

```
with bpy.data.libraries.load(filepath) as (data_from, data_to):
    for group_name in data_from.node_groups:
        print(group_name)
```

If I have a node group in the same blend file, it works fine with the following code:

```
maingroup = bpy.data.node_groups['_TEST'].nodes
for n in maingroup:
    if n.parent == maingroup['Frame']:
        print("Node '" + n.node_tree.name + "' is framed")
```

But when I try to read the information of a node group that is in another file, unfortunately it doesn't work.

Any suggestions for a solution?

Comment: Uh, I don't think so. We need some library (maybe it already exists) for parsing .blend files. I think currently one option is to run Blender in a separate process, opening a file and reading necessary information there… I think I've seen some existing answers on BSE using this technique.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Thanks for your feedback! ...that's what I was afraid of. Is there instead a way to add the nodegroups, then process them, and finally reliably remove them (without accidentally deleting existing nodegroups)?

Comment: But the question is why would you need to check this? What are you trying to solve? :D

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I want to create a submenu structure for node groups ...a further development of the "Node Presets" addon: https://github.com/quellenform/blender-NodePresetsExtended Here, all nodes that are packed into frames are to be put into a submenu.

Comment: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender-asset-tracer  *"BAT can be used as a Python library to inspect the contents of blend files, without having to open Blender itself. "*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another approach using [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) to spawn a separate process so you don't have to directly load and store the data into the current blend file's `bpy.data`, but unfortunately it is a bit slow. I'm not sure how frequently you will need to invoke this. If the call is just made once to make all the checks, then I guess it might suffice for your addon. But nevertheless it might still be interesting.

```
import subprocess

return_keyword = "RETURN_VALUE:"

def check_blend_file(file_path, group_name):

    script = """
import bpy
 
def load_test():
    file_path = "{}"
    group_name = "{}"
    with bpy.data.libraries.load(file_path) as (data_from, data_to):
        data_to.node_groups.append(group_name)
    maingroup = bpy.data.node_groups[group_name].nodes             
    for n in maingroup:
        if n.parent == maingroup['Frame']:
            return "Node '" + n.node_tree.name + "' is framed"
    return group_name + " not found"

result = load_test()
print("{}", result)
    """.format(file_path, group_name, return_keyword)

    command = ["blender", "--background", "--python-expr", script]

    result = subprocess.check_output(command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, text=True)
    return_value = "No result found"

    for line in result.splitlines():
        if return_keyword in line:
           return_value = line.replace(return_keyword, "")

    return return_value

return_value = check_blend_file("C:/Users/harry/Downloads/test.blend", "_TEST")

print("Return value:", return_value)
```

Comment: This looks very promising! Please give me a little time to try around with it....

Comment: Regarding the question asked, this solution works perfectly, so I mark it as *Accepted Answer*. However, it is unfortunately not suitable for my use case, because the background process simply takes too long. The script would be called only once, but always when the submenu is opened for the first time. Fortunately, I came up with a simpler solution in the meantime, and now control the submenu items via the name of the node group (via a split character). I will then publish the changes on [Github](https://github.com/quellenform/blender-NodePresetsExtended). Thanks again!

Comment: awesome! glad u were able to come up with a solution to your issue!

Comment: ....But... I may solve it this way after all. Then I could even spare myself the different paths in the preferences and solve it there via a button, as well as use a JSON file as a cache. Hm. Off-topic, but what do you think about it? Chat?

Comment: how does chat work? when u open blender doesnt all the loading for different addons happen there then u can cache the results?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147984/discussion-on-answer-by-harry-mckenzie-how-can-i-read-the-properties-of-a-node-g); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @[MarkusVonBroady](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/60486/markus-von-broady) for his contribution to the previous script version, here is the final script that should work. Since the `libraries.load` only loads object names, by adding the names we want to load to `data_to`, i.e. `data_to.node_groups.append('_TEST')`, only then will the data we specify get loaded into `bpy.data` after the `with` block exists, that is when the Context Manager's `__exit__` method gets called. This way you can control what data to load and you can do your checks.

```
import bpy
 
def load_test():
    file_path = "C:/Users/harry/Downloads/test.blend"
    with bpy.data.libraries.load(file_path) as (data_from, data_to):
        data_to.node_groups.append('_TEST')
    maingroup = bpy.data.node_groups['_TEST'].nodes             
    for n in maingroup:
        if n.parent == maingroup['Frame']:
            print("Node '" + n.node_tree.name + "' is framed")
    return True
 
success = load_test() # succeeds and test for frame works
```

Comment: I think instead of `data_to.node_groups = [group_name]` you want `data_to.node_groups.append(group_name)`, otherwise you will keep overwriting the `node_groups`, and will only import the last found node_group. Another problem is the general exception statement, I recommend you let the exception happen, and once it does, note the error type and ignore it specifically.

Comment: And your problem seems to be, that you try to read the newly added node_group from `bpy.data`, but it's not there yet: the actual import happens at the end of the `with` block, when the context manager's `__exit__` method is called. So you assemble a structure of things to load, then the `with` ends, the stuff in `data_to` is actually loaded, and then you can access it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, I had tried that with `data_to`, and as soon as the nodes are loaded with it, of course all information is available, but thereby all nodes are always imported (which I can't use in this case, unfortunately).  ...unless the nodes imported in this way can be reliably removed again after parsing, but so far I have not succeeded in doing that either.

Comment: I think this code is equivalent to the above: https://pastebin.com/fakbFC1v - I haven't tested and I already noticed I forgot to add `maingroup = bpy.data.node_groups['_TEST']` between lines 6 and 7 but you get the idea.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady hey cool you made it work! i'll update the answer! ok now i understand that the `with` completes the load only after it exists. thanks for your input! Since the `libraries.load` only loads all the names, by adding the names to the `data_to` like `data_to.node_groups.append('_TEST')` only then will the specific data we specify get loaded into `bpy.data` after the `with` exists, so not everything is loaded if i understood it correctly.

Comment: @quellenform I'd like to clarify. so you don't want anything to get loaded at all into `bpy.data` and just directly be able to parse the blend to do the checks? so if you don't want anything loaded into the current `bpy.data`, will it suffice if this was done in another subprocess? if not then you will definitely need a binary parsing method which i doubt exists as of the moment :(

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Yes, that is correct. The addon is about reading the node groups contained in a blend file and wrapping them in a menu. Currently, however, all node groups are not listed hierarchically, which quickly becomes confusing with many groups. To create submenus, I would have to be able to recognize how they should be nested when reading the file, and a direct import does not help me. The idea of a subprocess sounds interesting though! I just have no idea how this works. And I wonder why Blender doesn't have a parser for its own file format, but that's another story.