# How can I save Geometry Nodes group?

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes

I want to be able to apply different Geometry Nodes Groups to my design.

Is there a  way to store them and switch between them as needed?

EDIT:

I noticed that Node Tree dropdown list (or menu, or whatever this thing is called) can store multiple presets/collections of Nodes Groups, although it seems like it can save only one preset and the other ones disappear after closing Blender.

[image]

Comment: Not really. I would make each variation a group and apply some [switch](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/switch.html) nodes to choose which configuration to use...

Comment: @healthyfat, what exactly do you mean? What do you mean by "configurations"? Is it different node trees for different functions, or something like group input value presets you are talking about? Could you provide some more context and possibly an example of how and for what you would want to use these "configurations"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249624/how-to-make-an-asset-library-for-node-groups/268548#268548

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys By configuration I mean Node Tree or one group of Nodes. 

I guess Node Tree browser may be what I am looking for, although it saves only one preset.

Comment: There is no such thing as Node Tree Browser in Blender. Maybe you meant Asset Browser?

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys: What is the name of that browser on the picture I included above? It is located in Geo Nodes panel and it allows to browse Node Trees.

Comment: It's Geometry Node Editor. See the solutions quellenform links to in the comments above.

Comment: No. Its is not Geometry Node Editor. It is inside that panel, but it looks and behave like a browser. 


"See the solutions quellenform links to in the comments above."

I already did.

Comment: What you see here in the dropdown are the node groups currently used in your open blend file. The asset browser and the node presets are completely different things. These allow you to reuse previously saved node groups from other files or locations. Please try to clarify what you are asking about in this question.

Comment: "The asset browser and the node presets are completely different things."
Thank you for insight, although I know what asset browser is and I don't talk about it nowhere here. I did mention Node Tree browser in reference to dropdown list with node groups in Geometry Nodes panel, because I don't know proper name and the Blender tooltip shows "Browse Node Tree" so I refer to it as Node Tree Browser, which I was obviously wrong about and I apologise for the confusion. As for my question I want to switch between different Node Groups and be able to save those Groups in separate presets or files.

Comment: Ah, sorry, now I understand what you mean. In this case the answer below already fits (somehow). You would need to use *Fake User* here, so that the node group in your file is preserved when saving, without them being explicitly in use.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to save Geometry Node groups.

As you can see in the [answers linked in the comments already](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249624/how-to-make-an-asset-library-for-node-groups/268548#268548), you can use [Asset Browser](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/asset_browser.html) for it. You should look into how the Asset Browser works in general first. Short version is: you mark Blender's data blocks as assets, and save them to some files in some folder that you set up as your asset library in Blender's preferences and then Blender loads those assets from those files in the folder as your asset library in the Asset Browser. This works for all sorts of stuff in Blender, node trees/groups including. This is probably the best way to do it and you should look into that.

I wanted to mention another way for very specific situation. If you want to save some things that you use all the time in pretty much all kinds of projects you do, you can save Blender's [data blocks]([data blocks](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/data_blocks.html) are objects, meshes, materials, textures, particle systems, material/compositing/GN node groups and pretty much all and any kind of data Blender saves in a file) to the default [startup file](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/startup_scene.html), so they are available when you open Blender with the default scene. In order to do so, you need to open Blender with it's default startup scene and append everything you want from other files or make it there and make sure all the stuff that is not yet used has ["Fake User"](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/data_blocks.html#protected). It's usually the shield icon and you can find it all over the UI, but in case of Geometry Nodes it's here:

[image]

There are other ways of setting Fake User like in the Outliner:

[image]

Once you have everything you want in the file and also everything you don't want removed you can save it as default Startup file:

[image]

Keep in mind that everything is saved even things like UI and tool settings and you will always have that file loaded when you start Blender so it makes sense to make it convenient for what you do with Blender.